# SQL Get average of values in left table if there is record in B table

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying to average records in table A if there is at least 1 matching record in table B:

```
SELECT AVG  ( A.w )
FROM A
INNER JOIN B on A.pk  = B.fk
WHERE B.v = 5
```

Based on the sample data described below, I would expect a result of **50** i.e. there are 6 records in B where v = 5 and fk = A, and one record where v = 5 and fk = B, so I'm getting 85.714...

Thank you in advance for your wisdom!

```
Values in Table A
+---+---+
|pk | w |
+---+---+
| A |100|
| B | 0 |
| C |500|
| D | 5 |
+---+---+

Table B
+---+---+
|fk | v |
+---+---+
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 10|
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 9 |
| D | 7 |
+---+---+
```

Comment: how did you calculate  85.714  based on your sample data?

Comment: ( 6*100 + 0 ) / 7 = 85.714...

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT AVG( A.w )
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.pk = B.fk AND B.v = 5);
```

You are not taking into account that the `JOIN` is multiplying the number of rows in `A` that are used for the average.

For performance you want an index on `B(fk, v)`.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to not multiply the value!

Sadly the EXISTS clause seems to be choking my SQL Engine

Comment: @JulienLafleur . . . Interesting.  I wouldn't expect the performance to be worse than the `join` . . . unless perhaps `A` has an index on `pk`.  However, with a name like `pk` one would expect both tables to have an index on the value (all primary keys do have indexes automatically in almost all databases).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that differently.  The clause does not process at all, and returns an error.    :-(

Comment: @JulienLafleur . . . The syntax looks correct to me.